# Search Result webpart query showing 0 results however Result source search query is returning all results

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, search, search-results

I have come across this unusual issue in SharePoint 2013. I have requirement to search file server for which I created a content source and ran full crawl.

All crawls were successful and verified from crawl log also. After this I created Result source and through Query builder tool specified the content source as Newly created Content Source and ran the query here also I got the desired results.

But after modifying the search result web part through query builder tool and running the same query as was in result source the query resulted in 0 results. What am I missing?

Comment: Are you using the same account in both cases?

Comment: NO, actually while creating search webpart , I am using FBA account as it the site collection administrator is an FBA account, while Creating content source i had used AD account.